# Algebraic factors in any order RegExr

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that matches factors of a polynomial. It has to be true or false. It either matches or it doesn't. For example:

> (x-5)(x+2)(x-1)

Of course these three factors can be in any order but cannot have duplicates. I can have duplicates but most of the time I can't. So I think if I can figure it out without duplicates that tweaking it a bit to allow duplicates should be easy.

This is what I tried:

> ^\(x-5\)|\(x\+2\)|\(x-1\)$

But that doesn't allow for any order. I also need this to work with even more factors. I need to have any number of factors in any order. Sometimes

I should mention that I cannot run code. I am using a online program called Canvas. I only have one line to work with. It is an automatic grader. So I am checking to see if the student typed in the correct answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you have duplicates? surely `(x-1)(x-1)` is a valid set of factors (of `x^2-2x+1`)

Comment: That is true and I will have some of those, but for now I need to make it without duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Based on OPs comments that they cannot run code and must check for duplicates, this regex will work for up to 3 factors:

```
^(\(x[+-]\d+\))((?!\1)(\(x[+-]\d+\))((?!(\1|\3))(\(x[+-]\d+\)))?)?$
```

The regex looks for a factor `\(x[+-]\d+\)`. Then it checks that this is not followed by the same factor using a negative look-ahead `(?!\1)` and another factor. It then checks that this is not followed by either previously used factors using a negative look-ahead again `(?!(\1|\3)` and the finally a third factor. The second and third factors are made optional to allow for matching a pattern up to 3 factors. The regex could be expanded to 4 or more factors by repeating the pattern of nested negative look-ahead and factor as many times as required. For 4 factors the negative look-ahead would be `(?!(\1|\3|\6))`.

[Updated demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/53qeFR/4)

**Original answer**

This regex will deal with an arbitrary number of factors but I think you will have to deal with duplicates in your application. However I'm not sure that duplicates shouldn't be allowed anyway since (for example) `(x-1)(x-1)` is a valid set of factors of `x^2-2x+1`.

```
^(\(x[+-]\d+\))+$
```

The regex looks for an arbitrary number of groups of `(` followed by `x`, a `+` or `-`, some digits (`\d+`) followed by a closing `)`. By enclosing the regex in `^` and `$` we ensure it has to match the whole string.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/53qeFR/3/)

If you do want to check for duplicates this is how you could do it in PHP. It uses [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split the string at the point between factors (using a positive look-behind for a `)` and a positive look-ahead for a `(`), and then compares the count of the array with the count of the unique values in the array to decide if there are duplicates:

```
$factors = '(x-5)(x+2)(x-1)(x+2)';
$factors = preg_split('/(?<=\))(?=\()/', $factors);
print_r($factors);
if (count($factors) != count(array_unique($factors))) {
    echo "duplicate factors found!";
};
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => (x-5)
    [1] => (x+2)
    [2] => (x-1)
    [3] => (x+2) 
)
duplicate factors found!
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/1l9qD)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I cannot run code. I only have one line to work with and it gives me // to start with. I can't even add a 'g' at the end.

Comment: @CraigOgden I've updated my answer with a regex only solution that will work for up to 3 factors, and is reasonably easy to expand to more although the number of factors it can process will always be limited by the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following regex:

```
(\([^\)]*\))
```

This will capture anything that starts with `(` plus anything that is not a `)` and a final `)`.

This has the benefit that it does not depend on the letter of the variable `x`.
It will even capture incorrect factors like `(2x+3)` (and later drop them or factor correctly).

Using this regex in JavaScript with `match` will return an array with each factor.

```js
var pattern = /(\([^\)]*\))/g;

str = "(y-1)(y+1)"
console.log(str.match(pattern))

str = "(X+0)(X+15)(X+21)(X-3)(X+4)"
console.log(str.match(pattern))
```

#### No Duplicates:

If you only want to keep one of each match do:

```
factors = [... new Set(str.match(/(\([^\)]*\))/g))]
```

where str is your factorized polynomial

```js
str = "(x+1)(x+2)(x+1)(x+2)"

console.log( [... new Set(str.match(/(\([^\)]*\))/g))] )
```

Comment: I cannot run code. It has to be all in one line. The program I am using is a web based program called Canvas.

Comment: It is in one line if you substitute pattern like this: `str.match(/(\([^\)]*\))/g)`

Comment: That allows duplicates. So (x-5)(x-5)(x-1) would still match. Thanks for trying to help. I need to have any number of factors in any order. Sometimes I can have duplicates but most of the time I can't.

Comment: @CraigOgden Edited answer to a single line code that removes duplicate elements.